# How do I weigh values by their relative frequency and then get an average?

Tags: robust, measurement, weighted-mean

Suppose I have three values that were measured repeatedly in a study. The conditions imply that the values should be close to each other, i.e. ideally three times the same value.

The measured values are: 20, 21 and 1.

One can assume that 0.5 is not representative of the real value, but one doesn't know for sure.

So one would like to have some statistical foundation to choose a likely value, i.e. representative of the real world.

What I have in mind is to give 20 and 21 more weight, since the distance to each other is smaller than between 21 and 1 or 20 and  1. Why? Because it is not so likely to measure two values that close if they weren't representative.

Some VAGUE idea is to do (20 + 20 + 21 + 21 + 1)/5.

But I'm looking, if there is, for something more sophisticated.

Is there such a thing and if yes, what do I have to compute?'

Comment: Do you have some knowledge about what these values should be?

Comment: Taking the median of 3 is enough to protect you against one outlier.

Comment: @user2974951: Thank you! Real values are the amount weight of clay (as a soil fraction) from  100 g of soil. The weights can only be handled relative to each other.The mesasured values from the same spot were 1.84, 1.73 and 0.405 grams resp.

Comment: OK, do you have some knowledge about what the ratio of clay to soil should be?

Comment: @user2974951 Thanks. Since one of the values of the abve set is still lacking I take another set: 0.355, 1.54, 1.45 g clay.  There was a measurement of the percentage of clay for the field from where the above samples were taken: its is 25.92% of clay in the soil. (I have 5 measurements like the latter, but approx. 14 different locations. I need to find a relation between the clay measurements from the lab and the real-world measurements also). Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you might benefit from Bayesian analysis assuming a spiky distribution with heavy tails. The median that @NickCox mentioned materializes with the assumed Laplace / double exponential distribution of the data.